# How to get instagram access token via website - can access public_content?

Tags: token, generator, instagram

I known some website can get access token Instagram

http://instagram.pixelunion.net/

http://www.jetseotools.com/instagram/
...

I want to get my list video LIKED
But it just access basic information, Not have permission access public content
I remember have some website can generator token with public_content permission
but I cant find back again

Please help me! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://axentmedia.com/instagram-access-token/) one can generate token that has permission to access public content

Comment: This link have die. Please give me another site !

Comment: Instagram has closed their api for public content, so you can't get public feed anymore. You can check this: https://www.instagram.com/developer/